# rosinstall_generator

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i type this """rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro fuerte --deps > fuerte-desktop-full.rosinstall""" in the terminal the output is "" bash: fuerte-desktop-full.rosinstall: Permission denied """ How can this be solved ????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156056/rosinstall_generator/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to write somewhere, where you are not allowed to write.
Change to your home directory or similar.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0